# Node JS object return as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have an express api endpoint.

and my createS service like that:

```
async function createS(name, user_ids) {
    const seg = new Seg ({
        name : name,
        user_ids : user_ids
    })

      await seg.save().then(doc => {
          console.log(doc);===============>>> not undefined
          return {doc}
      }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});

}
```

And my controller like that:

```
async function createS(req,res,next){
    const sName = req.body.name;
    const user_ids = req.body.user_ids;
    console.log("*****")
    segService.createS(sName, user_ids).then(function (doc){
        console.log(doc)=============================================>>> undefined
    })
```

I know that this problem depends on asynchronous process. And I tried several type of solution Also Im new on Node JS.

Why Im getting this error? How can I solve this error?

Comment: You're not returning anything from either `createS` function. Also, mixing `async/await` with `then` is a bad idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Your `createS` service needs to return a promise as opposed to the actual `doc`

Refactor your service to look like this

```js
async function createS(name, user_ids) {
  const seg = new Seg ({
    name : name,
    user_ids : user_ids
  })

  return seg.save()
}
```

Comment: It looks good, but. in this case in the controller you have to handle the error. And also you might leave the `async`

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Do you mind giving it an upvote?

Comment: some error happend during your post edit.
Im pasting it here:
Controller error handling:
async function createS(req,res,next){
    const sName = req.body.name;
    const user_ids = req.body.user_ids;
    console.log("*****")
    try {
      const doc = await segService.createS(sName, user_ids)
      console.log(doc);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }  
}